# how does multilevel page table save memory spaces

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

So I have learned that [Multilevel page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#Multilevel_page_table) is good at saving memory spaces during memory paging/mapping period.
Suppose I have a `page directory` with **n** items, so I will have **n** `page table`, so it costs just as large as space as single-level page table.
Is there anything I missed?

Comment: You don't always map every single page. Hence, you won't need a second level page table for those entries.

Comment: @tangrs What does it mean exactly? Does it mean, when I require a `page table`, the system will fetch it for me?

Answer (score 0):

In multilevel page table there is one root page table that is present in the main-memory and all other page tables are kept in virtual memory. The root page table always remain in main memory. So, when you require a particular page table it will be loaded to the main memory while all other are still kept in virtual memory i.e page tables stored in virtual memory can be swapped in and out as and when required.